# I'm starting out in the language

Tags: meaning

Can anyone explain to me what this sentence means

{don't be lengthy you should talk concisely} ????
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means don't use a lot of words.  Keep your answer very brief (short) and to the point, (on the subject).